# MySQL check rows that has all kinds of another row

Tags: mysql

I want to know if there is a query to get some rows that have all kinds of another row

I have an example table like this

```
id  Col_1   Col_2
 1.  A       1
 2.  A       2
 3.  A       3
 4.  A       4
 5.  B       1
 6.  B       2
 7.  B       3
 8.  C       1
 9.  C       2
10.  D       3
```

In this case, `Col_2` can only contain 1 - 4

The expected result is the query would produce

```
id  Col_1   Col_2
 1.  A       1
 2.  A       2
 3.  A       3
 4.  A       4
```

Because A has all kinds of `Col_2`

Comment: A simple solution would self join where another table contains total count per Col_1. Can we have two or more records for single mapping i.e. two records of `B 1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets your table name is `test`.

```
SELECT 
    t1.id,
    t1.Col_1,
    t1.Col_2
FROM test t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT t2.Col_1
    FROM test t2
    WHERE t2.Col_2 IN (2, 3)  -- Add where clause here
    GROUP BY t2.Col_1
    HAVING COUNT(0) = 2 -- change count based on where, you can also use COUNT(DISTINCT Col_2)
) AS temp ON t1.Col_1 = temp.Col_1
WHERE t1.Col_2 IN (2,3);  -- Add here too, to make sure you only get 2 records for A and B.
```

Comment: Gonna give it a try

Comment: This query works, but how if the problem is we only have a list of desired `Col_2` as input (e.g. input `[2, 3]` would produce A and B, because both A and B have `Col_2` values 2 and 3)?

Comment: Do this, use where clause in inner query and update the count. See my updated answer.

Comment: @r880505, see my updated answer and if it works for you, do accept the answer.